# Pygame not updating screen with pause

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-clock

I was trying to use pygame to create a script that upon clicking run. The window changes the colours of the screen to blue, grey, red with one second delays between them, and then exit out of that loop and then run the game as per normal being the `print("cycle done")` code. Unfortunately what happens is that the window opens, hangs for around 3 seconds and then shows a red screen, rather than going through each of the colours.

```
import pygame as pg

running = True
calibration = False
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((600, 400))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
timer = 0

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

    if not calibration:
        pg.time.wait(1000)
        screen.fill(blue)
        pg.display.flip()

        pg.time.wait(1000)
        screen.fill(green)
        pg.display.flip()

        pg.time.wait(1000)
        screen.fill(red)
        pg.display.flip()

        calibration = True
        print(calibration)

    print("cycle done")
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Hmm, works fine on my machine. The expected output is blue for 1 second, green for 1 second and then remain red?

Comment: Yes that exactly what I want to happen, Im using a Mac, may I know what you're running it on?

Comment: I'm running it on windows 10 and using pygame 1.9.6

Comment: Im using the same version of pygame. Know what could be causing the issue then?

Comment: Python 3.7.7, pygame 2.0.0.dev6, win10 works fine as well. Which program are you using to run the code?

Comment: I’m using pycharm, on the masters release on MacOS

Comment: Try it using IDLE or sublime. Also try with `import time` -> `time.sleep(1)`. I'm afraid I can't help any more, I have no experience with Mac

Comment: Yeah I’ve tried that that didn’t work either

Comment: Python 3.7.5, works fine on my Kubuntu distro.

Comment: It's possible that Mac expects the event loop to be checked every time the window updates. In that case, try adjusting the program to run your event loop between color cycles.

Comment: Something like this might work:

[...]

        `if not calibration:`

            `pg.time.wait(1000)`

            `screen.fill(blue)`

           `pg.display.flip()`

            `pg.event.pump()`
    
            `pg.time.wait(1000)`

            `screen.fill(green)`

            `pg.display.flip()`

            `pg.event.pump()`

    
            `pg.time.wait(1000)`

            `screen.fill(red)`

            `pg.display.flip()`

            `pg.event.pump()`
    
            `calibration = True`

            `print(calibration)`

Comment: Hi yes that worked thank you so much you might want to post that as an answer since it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you just wait for some time, you can use [`pygame.time.wait`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) or [`pygame.time.delay`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay). However, if you want to display a message and then wait some time, you need to update the display beforehand. The display is updated only if either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
is called. See [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

> This will update the contents of the entire display.

Further you've to handles the events with [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump), before the update of the display becomes visible in the window. See [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

This all means that you have to call `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.event.pump()` before `pygame.time.wait()`:

```py
while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

    if not calibration:
        
        pygame.event.pump()
        pg.time.wait(1000)
        
        screen.fill(blue)

        pg.display.flip()
        pygame.event.pump()
        pg.time.wait(1000)

        screen.fill(green)
        
        pg.display.flip()
        pygame.event.pump()
        pg.time.wait(1000)

        screen.fill(red)
        
        pg.display.flip()
        pygame.event.pump()
        pg.time.wait(1000)

        calibration = True
        print(calibration)

    print("cycle done")
    clock.tick(60)
```